# Replacement for system monitor applet for 17.10

Tags: system-monitor, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

When using 17.04 I used the system monitor applet to provide at a glance monitoring. CPU, Memory, Network etc

When I upgraded to 17.10 this applet became unusable as it was far too small to be practical. I tried to tweak it but nothing worked.

Is there a suitable replacement in 17.10?

I have tried installing the gnome extension [system monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) but have not succeeded.

[This one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1064/system-monitor/) installs but it does not give me bars. I have to open it to see the stats.

[This one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) complains about missing dependencies even though when all the requested dependencies are installed.

Comment: Have you  run `sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0  gir1.2-clutter-1.0` to make [system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) work?

Comment: yes I have run this.

output: 
gir1.2-clutter-1.0 is already the newest version (1.26.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1).
gir1.2-gtop-2.0 is already the newest version (2.38.0-1).
gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 is already the newest version (1.8.4-1ubuntu3).

Comment: Have you logged out and log in again after installing the extension? It works fine for me!

Comment: Glad to know that, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The extension [system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) depends on a few packages. To install them, run

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

Then log out and log in again as some extensions are not loaded properly right away. Alternatively if you're in an Xorg session (instead on Wayland) you may restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

System monitor gnome extension works fine, you just have to remove indicator-multiload via apt-get, which was blocking it from working and relogin afterwards. Command I used is:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-multiload
```

Comment: Not sure if I have that installed but it worked after a reboot

Answer (score 2):

The GNOME extension [system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) works. To install:

```
sudo apt install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

If you already have indicator-multiload for Unity installed, remove it:

```
sudo apt remove indicator-multiload
```

Log out and log in again as some extensions are not loaded properly right away. You may be able to restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then typing `r` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You may need to install the gnome-tweak-tool to activate the Extension:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open Tweaks app, then select Extensions, then turn System Monitor on.